# Guards BjyAuthorize Always 200 (which should be 403) Status Code in Unit Test

Tags: unit-testing, zend-framework, bjyauthorize

I'm trying to create unit test using BjyAuthorize, the guard works well in browser ( return 403 ) but it doesn't work in unit test because it's always return 200 (which should be 403).

here are my codes :

Bjyauthohrize.global.php

```
<?php

return [
'bjyauthorize' => [

    // set the 'guest' role as default (must be defined in a role provider)
    'default_role' => 'guest',

    'identity_provider' => \BjyAuthorize\Provider\Identity\ZfcUserZendDb::class,

    // Using the authentication identity provider, which basically reads the roles from the auth service's identity
//        'identity_provider' =>    \BjyAuthorize\Provider\Identity\AuthenticationIdentityProvider::class,

    'role_providers'        => array(

        \BjyAuthorize\Provider\Role\ZendDb::class => [
            'table'                 => 'user_role',
            'identifier_field_name' => 'id',
            'role_id_field'         => 'role_id',
            'parent_role_field'     => 'parent_id',
        ],

        // using an object repository (entity repository) to load all roles into our ACL
//            BjyAuthorize\Provider\Role\ObjectRepositoryProvider::class => array(
//                'object_manager'    => 'doctrine.entitymanager.orm_default',
//                'role_entity_class' => 'User\Entity\Role',
//            ),
    ),

    /* Currently, only controller and route guards exist
     *
     * Consider enabling either the controller or the route guard depending on your needs.
     */
   'guards' => [
       \BjyAuthorize\Guard\Route::class => [
           ['route' => 'zfcuser', 'roles' => ['user']],
           ['route' => 'zfcuser/logout', 'roles' => ['user','administrator']],
           ['route' => 'zfcuser/login', 'roles' => ['guest']],
           ['route' => 'zfcuser/register', 'roles' => ['guest']],
           // Below is the default index action used by the ZendSkeletonApplication
           ['route' => 'home', 'roles' => ['guest', 'user']],
           ['route' => 'user/default', 'roles' => ['user']],
       ],
    ],
],
```

];

Bootstrap :

```
public static function init()
{
    $zf2ModulePaths = array(dirname(dirname(__DIR__)));
    if (($path = static::findParentPath('vendor'))) {
        $zf2ModulePaths[] = $path;
    }
    if (($path = static::findParentPath('module')) !== $zf2ModulePaths[0]) {
        $zf2ModulePaths[] = $path;
    }

    static::initAutoloader();

    // use ModuleManager to load this module and it's dependencies
    $testConfig = include __DIR__ . '/TestConfig.php';

    $baseConfig = array(
        'module_listener_options' => array(
            'module_paths' => $zf2ModulePaths,
        ),
    );

    $config = ArrayUtils::merge($testConfig, $baseConfig);

    $serviceManager = new ServiceManager(new ServiceManagerConfig());
    $serviceManager->setService('ApplicationConfig', $config);
    $serviceManager->get('ModuleManager')->loadModules();

    static::$serviceManager = $serviceManager;
    static::$config = $config;
}
```

setUp() :

```
 protected $serviceManager;
protected $controller;
protected $event;
protected $routeMatch;
protected $request;


public function setUp()
{
    $this->serviceManager = Bootstrap::getServiceManager();
    $this->controller = new IndexController($this->serviceManager->get('doctrine.entitymanager.orm_default'));
    $this->routeMatch = new RouteMatch(array('controller' => 'User\Controller\Index'));
    $this->request    = new Request();
    $this->event      = new MvcEvent();
    $config = $this->serviceManager->get('Config');
    $routerConfig = isset($config['router']) ? $config['router'] : array();
    $router = HttpRouter::factory($routerConfig);
    $this->event->setRouter($router);
    $this->event->setRouteMatch($this->routeMatch);
    $this->controller->setEvent($this->event);
    $this->controller->setServiceLocator($this->serviceManager);

    $this->mockZfcLogin();
    $this->mockBjy();

    parent::setUp();
}
```

TestAction:

```
 public function testUpdateProfileActionCanBeAccessed()
{
    $this->mockBjy('dodol');

    $this->routeMatch->setParam('action', 'updateProfile');

    $result   = $this->controller->dispatch($this->request);
    $response = $this->controller->getResponse();

    $this->assertEquals(403, $response->getStatusCode());
}
```

here is mockBjy and mockzfc :

```
protected function mockBjy($role = 'guest')
{
    $authorizeMock = $this
        ->getMockBuilder('BjyAuthorize\Provider\Identity\ProviderInterface')
        ->disableOriginalConstructor()
        ->getMock();

    $authorizeMock
        ->expects($this->any())
        ->method('getIdentityRoles')
        ->will($this->returnValue($role));

    $this->serviceManager->setAllowOverride(true)
        ->setService('BjyAuthorize\Provider\Identity\ProviderInterface', $authorizeMock);
}

protected function mockZfcLogin()
{
    $ZfcUserMock = $this->getMock('ZfcUser\Entity\User');

    $ZfcUserMock->expects($this->any())
        ->method('getId')
        ->will($this->returnValue('10'));

    $authMock = $this->getMock('ZfcUser\Controller\Plugin\ZfcUserAuthentication');

    $authMock->expects($this->any())
        ->method('hasIdentity')
        -> will($this->returnValue(true));

    $authMock->expects($this->any())
        ->method('getIdentity')
        -> will($this->returnValue($ZfcUserMock));

    $this->controller->getPluginManager()
        ->setService('zfcUserAuthentication', $authMock);
}
```

controller:

```
   public function updateProfileAction()
{
    Debug::dump($this->zfcUserAuthentication()->getIdentity()->getId());
    $authorize = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('BjyAuthorize\Provider\Identity\ProviderInterface');
    $roles = $authorize->getIdentityRoles();
    Debug::dump($roles);
 }
```

result :

```
Configuration read from /home/mockie/importants/htdocs/hommate/module/User/test/phpunit.xml

string(2) "10"

string(5) "guest"

Time: 122 ms, Memory: 7.00Mb

OK (1 test, 5 assertions)
```

Comment: what is `mockBjy` and why is it called in `setUp` **and** in the test itself?

Comment: @NDM I just inserted the mockBjy code, please take a look